# How can I use UIView animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

The animation does not work and the completion block is called right away. If I comment the code inside the completion block, everything runs as it should.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.waitingAnchorAcceptView.alpha = 0;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.waitingAnchorAcceptView removeFromSuperview];

    }];
```

Comment: This code should work and has been implemented very many times by very many developers including myself. Your issue must be somewhere else. Maybe animations are disabled in your context.

Comment: Thank you very much, My English is not very good

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
self.waitingAnchorAcceptView.alpha = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

  [self.view layoutIfNeeded];  

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.waitingAnchorAcceptView removeFromSuperview];

}];
```

Comment: `layoutIfNeeded`updates the positioning of views, not the `alpha` value

Answer (score -1):

You can study what you did or didn't do correctly by creating a new project and inserting this code in your view controller:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createButton];
}

- (void)createButton {

    UIButton *buttonThatWillHide = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0 + arc4random()%100,
                                                                              100.0 + arc4random()%200, 120.0, 60.0)];
    buttonThatWillHide.alpha = 0.0;
    NSArray *colors = @[[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor]];
    buttonThatWillHide.backgroundColor = colors[arc4random()%colors.count];
    [buttonThatWillHide setTitle:@"Press me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:buttonThatWillHide];

    [buttonThatWillHide addTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        buttonThatWillHide.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}

- (void)onButtonPress:(UIView *)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        sender.alpha = 0.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [sender removeFromSuperview];
    }];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self createButton];
    });
}

@end
```